# Gravity Forms: Create fields programmatically

Tags: custom-field, plugin-gravity-forms

Is there any possiblity to create and manage gravity fields dynamically?
I have form with ID `4` with couple fields. I want to add some fields of type `checkbox` with my own custom external data which can change in time and can be in many instance (not countable, today it can be 1 field, tommorow it could be 3 fields), so I can't add this fields permanently in form settings in admin panel. I try to follow `gform_pre_render` filter doucmentation and some other SO questions like [How to add Gravity Forms fields in gform_pre_render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399656/how-to-add-gravity-forms-fields-in-gform-pre-render?rq=1) but I'm stuck in some validation issues. Newly created fields should be required and when I try to submit the form this dynamically created fields get duplicates and half of them are red-marked required and the other half is not marked as required. Below are the code

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_4', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_4', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_4', 'populate_checkbox' );

$count = 101;
if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        ++$count;
        $query->the_post();
        $required = get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'required', true);

        $choices = array( array( 'text' => $query->post->post_content, 'value' => $query->post->ID ) );
        $inputs = array( array( 'label' => $query->post->post_content, 'id' => "{$count}" ) );
        
        $props = array( 
            'id' => $count,
            'clause' => $query->post->ID,
            'choices' => $choices,
            'inputs' => $inputs,
            'isRequired' => (bool) $required,
            'label' => 'My Field Label',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        );
        $field = GF_Fields::create( $props );
        array_push( $form['fields'], $field );
    }
}
```

Any clues will be much appreciate!

Comment: have you checked this post?
https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-custom-field-gravity-forms/

Comment: @Alejo_Blue I don't think wants to create custom field types.. he needs to dynamically add fields, for example at run time, for example.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem @Kamil ?